# javascript declaring variables or not

Tags: javascript

So this is puzzling to me. Are variables expensive?
Let's take a look at this code:

```
var div1 = document.createElement('div');
var div2 = document.createElement('div');

div2.appendChild(div1);
```

Now this one

```
var div2 = document.createElement('div');

div2.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
```

So, on the second example, I'm doing the same thing as on the first one. Is it more expensive to declare a variable than not? Do I save memory by just creating and using an element on the fly?

EDIT: this is a sample code to illustrate the question. I know that in this specific case, the memory saved (or not) in minimal.

Comment: Expense aside, I don't like to create variables that are only used once (that is, assigned a value at declaration and then used in only one other place). Particularly in longer code blocks I find this makes it harder to read because I'm left wondering where else the variable might be used, so for your simple example I'd go with the second version. Having said that, _sometimes_ a one-use variable makes the code easier to read if it saves having a really long line with lots of `object.method(otherObject.method()+another.method())` type calls. I guess I'm saying go with the most readable for you.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but the way you are building the DOM is actually quite expensive. Although using createElement is the ideal approach, appending html to a container's innerHTML (or using something like JQuery.append) is a lot faster, e.g. `document.getElementById('parentId').innerHTML += '<div>blah blah</div>'`

Answer (score 7):

Variables are *extremely* cheap in JavaScript, yet, no matter how cheap they are, everything has a cost.

Having said that, it's not a noticable difference, and you should be thinking more about making your code *readable* rather than performing micro-optimizations.

You should be using variables to save repeated operations. In your example above, it's likely you *need* the variable pointing to the newly created `div`, or you'll be able to do nothing to it... unless you end up retrieving it from the DOM; which will prove many times more costly than the variable, as DOM manipulation is one of the slowest parts of JavaScript.

Comment: +1 - I agree.  The primary goal of writing javascript is to make correct, reliable and readable code.  Tiny memory or performance optimizations are only worth making the code less readable when really, really needed.  In your case, either example is equally readable so you can do whichever seems clearer to you.

Comment: +1 I agree in this case. When the optimization is almost too small to measure, then readability/maintainability should be weighted heavily.

Comment: He doesn't necessarily have to get it from the DOM. He could always manipulate the reference returned from `appendChild` and do it all in-line.

Answer (score 4):

***In theory***, there is a ***tiny little amount*** of memory you save by not doing the variable declaration, because a variable declaration requires that the JavaScript engine creates a property on the *variable binding object* for the *execution context* in which you declare it. (See the specification, [Section 10.5](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5) and associated sections.)

***In reality***, you will never notice the difference, not even on a (relatively) slow engine like IE's. Feel free to use variables wherever they make the code clearer. Creating a property on a variable binding object (e.g., declaring a variable) is a very, very, *very* quick operation. (Avoid it at global scope, of course, but not because of memory use.)

***Caveat***: If the variable refers to a big memory structure that you only hold temporarily, *and* you create closures within that function context, the big memory structure *may* (in some engines) be kept in memory longer than necesary. Example:

```
function foo(element) {
    var a = /* ...create REALLY BIG structure here */;
    element.addEventListener("event", function() {
        // Do something **not** referencing `a` and not doing an `eval`
    }, false);
}
```

In an unsophisticated engine, since the event handler is a closure over the context of the call to `foo`, in theory `a` is available to the handler and so what it references remains "referencible" and not available for garbage collection until/unless that event handler function is no longer referencible. In any decent engine (like the V8 engine in Chrome), because you neither refer to `a` nor use `eval` within the closure (event handler), it's fine. If you want to defend yourself from mediocre engines, set `a` to `undefined` before `foo` returns, so the engine (no matter how mediocre) knows that the event handler won't be referencing that structure even if it were to reference `a`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link. Obviously my code is much, much, MUCH more complex that the sample I posted, I wouldn't be asking otherwise :)

Comment: @pec1985: Yeah, I figured. :-) But seriously: Don't worry about it. Make the code clear (whichever way that takes you). Also, in an optimizing engine (like the V8 engine in Chrome), odds are that the variable declaration doesn't survive the parsing anyway, if you never use it again. But it's fine even if it does.

Comment: "odds are that the variable declaration doesn't survive the parsing anyway" what is that mean? does it get minimized on fly? that's cool

Comment: @pec1985: By some engines, yes. By others, no. It depends a lot on what you do inside the function. Curiously enough, I was adding a caveat about that as you were commenting. :-) But even on engines where a lot of optimization isn't done, unless the variable is pointing to something *large* that is *temporary*, it doesn't matter. So we're talking edge case here, big time. The normal case is a no-brainer, use a variable if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you save memory, no it is in no way an amount that matters.